# Find the minimum number of MS Paint operations to fill a rectangle

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I found this problem somewhere in a contest and haven't been able to come up with a solution yet.

> I can "select", "copy", "insert" and "move" in another place a figures
>   on the screen. Initially I have the rectangle with size 1x1. What the least
>   quantity of these operations I have to do for building of another
>   rectangle, which size is AxB.

Here is my wrong code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#define size 1002
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int painta[size];
    int paintb[size];
    int i,j,a,b,temp;

    cin >> a >> b;
    if (a>b)
    {
        temp=a;
        a=b;
        b=temp;
    }

    painta[1]=4;
    for (i=2; i<=a; i++)
        painta[i]=painta[i-1]+2;

    for (i=2; i<=a; i++)
    {
        painta[2*i]=min(painta[i]+4,painta[2*i]);
        for (j=3*i; j<=a; j+=i)
        {
            painta[j]=min(painta[j-i]+2,painta[j]);
        }
    }

    paintb[1]=painta[a];
    paintb[2]=paintb[1]+4;

    for (i=3; i<=b; i++)
        paintb[i]=paintb[i-1]+2;

    for (i=2; i<=b; i++)
    {
        paintb[2*i] = min(paintb[i]+4,paintb[2*i]);
        for (j=3*i; j<=b; j+=i)
        {
            paintb[j]=min(paintb[j-i]+2,paintb[j]);
        }
    }
    cout << paintb[b] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the link: http://www.e-olymp.com/en/problems/18

Comment: Please explain your algorithm in plain english, to convey the intuition behind why you think it should work. Also, please cite the source of the problem so we can assure ourselves that it is not part of a live contest and so that we have the chance to try our own solutions

Comment: @Niklas B I've edited the question.

Comment: What's the "move" operation?

Comment: Try the test case `1 2`. Also consider `1 5` through `1 9`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is okay, though you've made some implementation mistakes that you could have found by checking some small testcases.

For example, one failing testcase is `1 2`, where your program gives the answer `8`, although `6` is correct. This is because you should have `a > b` instead of `b > a` for your algorithm to work:

```
-    if (a>b)
+    if (a<b)
```

Now we still have problems with testcases like `1 7`. The correct answer is 14, but your program answers 16. The reason is that you don't allow for overlapping inserts: Starting from a rectangle of size 1x2, we can use the sequence select, copy, insert+move, insert+move, insert+move, insert+move to get a rectangle of size 1x7. Considering this makes the program only slightly more complicated:

```
@@ -24,9 +24,10 @@
     for (i=2; i<=a; i++)
     {
         painta[2*i]=min(painta[i]+4,painta[2*i]);
-        for (j=3*i; j<=a; j+=i)
+        for (j=2*i+1; j<=a; j++)
         {
-            painta[j]=min(painta[j-i]+2,painta[j]);
+            int steps = (j - i - 1) / i;
+            painta[j]=min(painta[2*i]+2*steps,painta[j]);
         }
     }

@@ -39,9 +40,10 @@
     for (i=2; i<=b; i++)
     {
         paintb[2*i] = min(paintb[i]+4,paintb[2*i]);
-        for (j=3*i; j<=b; j+=i)
+        for (j=2*i+1; j<=b; j++)
         {
-            paintb[j]=min(paintb[j-i]+2,paintb[j]);
+            int steps = (j - i - 1) / i;
+            paintb[j]=min(paintb[2*i]+2*steps,paintb[j]);
         }
     }
```

Now there's still a small overflow here which might cause the program to crash for large inputs: You are accessing `painta[2*i]` and `paintb[2*i]` inside the loops. `i` can be up to `1000`, but the array only has size `1002`. Easy enough to fix:

```
@@ -5,12 +5,12 @@

 int main()
 {
-    int painta[size];
-    int paintb[size];
+    int painta[size*2];
+    int paintb[size*2];
     int i,j,a,b,temp;
```

Et voila, it passes all the test cases.